# Binary division - Highlighted an area of not understanding

Tags: math, binary

I have highlighted in green the area of which I don't understand. Can someone please explain to me where the 000 comes from? thanks :-)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a computing theory forum.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : move your picture around a little bit - line things up to make it easier

The first one on the top line is above the 2nd '1' in 1001
1 * 101 is 101, so subtract 101 from 1001, resulting in 11
Then since 100 is less < 101, the next numeral on the top line is '0', resulting in the '000' in green.